# How to split a certain attribute into two separate attributes in R dataset

Tags: r, split

I'm given a dataset  which contains an attribute `"year.month.repair"` and the data is displayed like `2009/4`

I am new to using R and i was wondering how to split the data into `"year.repair"` and `"month.repair"`. I have tried using `split(RepairTrain, RepairTrain$year.month.repair)` but i cannot find out how to get any further or how to correctly split it into the two attributes.

Thank You!

Comment: I guess `read.table(text = RepairTrain$year.month.repair, sep = "/")` should output two columns that you can, then, `cbind` with your `RepairTrain`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split a string you can use the `strsplit`function, specifying the "split".
(And format the returned list).

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(RepairTrain$year.month.repair, split = "/"))
```

Or in your case you can use `sub`

```
year.repair <- sub("[/].*", "", RepairTrain$year.month.repair)
month.repair <- sub(".*[/]", "", RepairTrain$year.month.repair)
```